# The orientation of this specific activity is set to be landscape but not the other

Tags: android

I use in the AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name="Zoom" android:text="@string/Name" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```

to force this specific Activity(B)  to be been see as landscape, my problem is when i am moving to the next Activity(c) or back to the Activity(A) its still show as landscape
what i should do different??

thanks for helping!!

Comment: Urrrm...remove android:screenOrientation="landscape" and let it decide which orientation to use when you rotate?

Comment: No but i went o this specific Activity to be on landscape but not the other Activity

Answer (score 1):

If your device is in landscape orientation, and you're not specifically setting orientation for the other activities, then they will show in landscape orientation.

Force the other activities to portrait with `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`.

This will mean if your device is in landscape and you switch activity, the new activity will display in portrait (on its side) and the user will then have to rotate the phone into portrait mode to view it correctly

Comment: In my app i don't take care of the orientation of the device so i just went in this specific Activity to be landscape but all the rest to be portrait